# visual studio 2008: HELP lost data!

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i opened a project and edited it and then i opened another copy of that project at the same time and some kind of message came up about the file being changed and whether i want to update the current file to the old file and i dont remember whether i said YES or NO, but after i opened the project it looks like it did not save my previous changes! is there any way to recover what i did/

Comment: Well if you don't even know what you have clicked and answered to those dialog boxes looks like you did not care much about it.

Comment: use a source control repository (TFS, SVN, or SourceSafe if you are desesperate). It won't help you to restore, but it will help you to not fall into this trap again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source control. Backups. When you edit a file outside of VS (or another copy of VS) VS will track cahnges made to the file. You can have VS not refresh the file.

Answer (score 4):

If you have decided to discard the changes and closed visual studio without saving, there is no way to recover pending changes. If you have reverted previous changes saving the old version of the project over the new one, same as before.

Next time avoid opening same project or solution twice and read and think about what you read on those dialog boxes. :)